# vba select values in listview and show in textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to display the value of 3rd column instead of 1st column. Pleae advise as to whan changed is required.

```
Dim blnFoundFirstItem As Boolean
blnFoundFirstItem = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ListView16.ListItems.Count
    If (ListView16.ListItems(i).Selected) Then
        If (Not blnFoundFirstItem) Then
            TextBox118.Text = ListView16.ListItems(i).Text
            blnFoundFirstItem = True
        Else
            TextBox118.Text = ListView16.ListItems(i).Text
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListSubItems()` :

```
Dim blnFoundFirstItem As Boolean
blnFoundFirstItem = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ListView16.ListItems.Count
    If (ListView16.ListItems(i).Selected) Then
        If (Not blnFoundFirstItem) Then
            TextBox118.Text = ListView16.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(3).Text
            blnFoundFirstItem = True
        Else
            TextBox118.Text = ListView16.ListItems(i).ListSubItems(3).Text
        End If
    End If
Next i
```